# Get the currentBlock as parameter in method - EPiServer MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, episerver

Greeting. I have a controller for my block containing this:

```
 public class QuestionBlockController : BlockController<QuestionBlock>
    {
        public override ActionResult Index(QuestionBlock currentBlock)
        {
            return PartialView(currentBlock);
        }

        public void Vote(QuestionBlock currentBlock)
        {
              //Do stuff
        }
```

The method Vote is invoked through an ajax call, seen in this View for the block:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Vote", "Vote", "QuestionBlock",
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "POST"
                        }, new { @class = "btn btn-vote" })
```

The problem is that when I click the actionlink it invokes the method Vote but currentBlock is **null**.

If I debug the currentBlock for Index method it is correctly set with the currentBlock as the current BlockData object.

What am I missing?

Regards,

ChrisRun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the suggestion to pass the currentBlock contentreference in as a parameter value to the ajax request.This works fine.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Vote", "Vote", "QuestionBlock", new {currentBlock = Model.ContentLink,
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "POST"
                        }, new { @class = "btn btn-vote" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should mention currentBlock parameter in your action link. If QuestionBlock is the Model of view that you are calling Ajax.ActionLink from, it should be like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Vote", "Vote", "QuestionBlock",Model,
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "POST"
                        }, new { @class = "btn btn-vote" })
```

and Model(currentBlock) will pass as parameter to Vote action.

Comment: Thanks for setting me in the right direction, but not entirely the correct answer. I've added my solution as an answer.